# Sublime Text 2 how to cancel automatic build?

Tags: build, sublimetext2

I'm having problem trying to stop Sublime Text 2 from build on save. I had previously installed SaveAllOnBuild plugin but I removed it. I have also made sure that Tools -> Save All on Build is turned off. In addition, I also checked my keyboard mapping, and Cmd+S is not listed as the keyboard binding

This is the snippet from the default binding file. User binding file is empty

```
{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["super+b"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Run"} },
```

I don't understand why Sublime keeps build on save. Any information would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install and uninstall the plugin? If you are using package control, what plugins are listed in the "Package Control-sublime-settings" file? Also, are there any additional packages that come up that aren't in that list if you search for "Package Control: List Packages" in the command palette?

Comment: @skuroda I added and remove the SaveAllOnBuild plugin through Package Control. However, I don't see any plugins listed in Package Control.sublime-settings. And I do not see SaveAllOnBuild folder in Packages/Package Control/

Comment: What other plugins besides that do you have installed? It's possible one of those also has some binding on the "save" listener. Also, can you go to Preferences -> Browse Packages and make sure the SaveAllOnBuild is not there. Plugins are installed at `Packages/<package name>`, not in the Package Control folder.